# Remove stamp from bill python

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, python-tesseract

Any ideas on how to remove the stamp from this bill prior to OCR processing?
[image]

Comment: Is it in the same spot for each bill? You could crop it out with something like pillow if it is.

Comment: That's the problem, it is not in the same spot..

Comment: If it is made solid white (without the lines behind the yellow), is that OK or must you have the lines?

Comment: It should be okay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read input
- Threshold on yellow
- Dilate to fill out rectangle
- Get largest contour
- Draw a white filled contour on the input image
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('form_with_label.jpg')

# threshold on yellow
lower=(0,200,200)
upper=(100,255,255)
thresh = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

# apply dilate morphology
kernel = np.ones((9,9), np.uint8)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

# get largest contour
contours = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(big_contour)

# draw filled white contour on input 
result = img.copy()
cv2.drawContours(result,[big_contour],0,(255,255,255),-1)

# save cropped image
cv2.imwrite('form_with_label_thresh.png',thresh)
cv2.imwrite('form_with_label_mask.png',mask)
cv2.imwrite('form_with_label_removed.png',result)

# show the images
cv2.imshow("THRESH", thresh)
cv2.imshow("MASK", mask)
cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thresholded Image:

[image]

Morphology Dilated Image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: One additional step would be to repair the missing lines with horizontal + vertical kernel

Comment: Any instruction on how to do that @nathancy ?

Comment: Use Hough line transform to get the equations for the (mostly horizontal) lines then re-draw them extended from side to side as as long as needed in the direction needed.